# Добрый день, вопрос по пхп и bin2hex

Tags: php

Знающие подскажите после прогонки bin2hex пробелы остаются в хексе как "20" как сделать пробелы как "00" ?

Comment: предварительно прямо в bin заменить пробелы на \x00 обычным replace

Comment: задача немного другая..
нужно вставить нулбайты в посл каж символа строки http://music.music/music.mp3
join('  ', str_split("http://music.music/music.mp3")
а вот после bin2hex join('  ') \x20 не становится \x00 :)

Comment: а почему он должен им стать, если пробел имеет код 0x20, почему бы в join явно не написать \x00

Comment: м, так получится же h\x00t\x00t\x00p\x00:\x00/\x00/\x00m\x00u\x00s\x00i\x00c\x00.\x00m\x00u\x00s\x00i\x00c\x00/\x00m\x00u\x00s\x00i\x00c\x00.\x00m\x00p\x003 на выходе..

Comment: почему это ? вы же сплитите строку, потом собираете с нулями а уже после этого применяете bin2hex

Comment: Вы же, надеюсь, догадываетесь заключать \x00 в _двойные_ кавычки что бы символы экранирования раскрылись ?

Comment: спасибо, действительно порядок выполнения перепутал